# how to run issubset/issuperset on a list of sets will iterating through that list

Tags: python

i'm trying to figure out how i can identify which objects are a subset/superset within the list that holds them.  and thereby remove them from the list.

```
if i have list a = [
                  {'john-123'},
                  {'john-123','john-234'},
                  {'john-123','john-234','johnnybegood'}  ]
```

the first two are subsets of the last one.

i've found a lot about comparing two different sets, but not sure how to implement that into an iteration

i've tried something like this:

```
for j in a:
        frequency = sum(j.issubset(b) for b in a)
        print(frequency)
```

but no dice

Comment: I dont understand what you are looking for. What do you expect for the example you give? What do you mean with 'no dice'? (sry, maybe my english isnt that good)

Comment: @H.Doebler  well... for each j in the list (meaning for each set in the list) i want to identify if it is a subset or not.  no dice means, unlucky or 'isn't working'

Comment: A subset of what? A subset of any set in the list? A subset of all sets in the list? A subset of all subsequent subsets in the list?

Comment: @H.Doebler whether it is a a subset of any other set in the same list.

Comment: Ok, obviously every set in the list is a subset of itself. But you want the list of elements that are a subset of an *other* set in the list. Can you assume that the list's elements are unique? I.e. is `a = [{1}, {1,2}, {1}]` a possible input to your problem?

Comment: @H.Doebler the list's elements are all unique - i've made sure of that. so that is not a possible input.  more like : a = [{'1'},{'1','2'},{'1','2','5'}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your approach is that you test every element in the list against every element in the list, not every *other* element. Since every set is a subset of itself, you will always get the whole list as an answer.

Try this:

```
a = [{1}, {2}, {1,2}, {1,3}, {1,3,4}]
```

Clearly, `{1,2}` and `{1,3,4}` are not subsets of other sets in `a`.

```
subsets = [b for b in a if any(b.issubset(c) and b != c for c in a)]
print(subsets)
[{1}, {2}, {1, 3}]
```